# Using impersonation in VB.Net 2009 Event System

Tags: event-system, 2009

We currently have part of our event system, that on the creation of content on a specific schema, a new component is created, taking values from the original. I have set this up so that the auto-created component automatically completes the first step in workflow, which then sends the workflow down a path to exit workflow.

The problem I now have is that this only works when the user doing the original creation is a system admin, with workflow privileges. When they are not, the item stays in workflow.

I think I can get around this by doing the auto-creation by impersonating the system account, which then would have the priveledges, but can't work out how to write it. Event code is in VB.Net, using Tridion 2009 SP1

Comment: Please post your VB.NET code where you create the TDSE object and perform the component creation.

Answer (score 1):

```
Tridion.ContentManager.Interop.TDS.TDSE tdse = new Tridion.ContentManager.Interop.TDS.TDSE();
tdse.Impersonate("DOMAIN\\tridionadmin");
tdse.Initialize();
```

Comment: In order Raul's code to work the current user must be an Impersonation user. It is a bad practice to make default or interactive users Impersonation users.
One of the options is to create a COM+ App that runs under an impersonation user account and acts like a wrapper/factory around a "System" TDSE object. You can contact Tridion Customer Support for the exact documentation.